# Getting original filename in Struts2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

How can I get original filename of an uploaded file in Struts2. Currently what I am getting is a filename.tmp filename whereas the file being uploaded is a CSV and the filename is different to what I am getting. Here is the JSP code

Select file
                                        Change
                                        
                                    
                                    Remove

Here is the action mapping in struts config

```
        <action name="survey/send" class="surveyAction" method="send">
            <interceptor-ref name="authorizationStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">20971520</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">orgAdmin.survey.send.settings</result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">orgAdmin.survey.send.settings</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles">orgAdmin.survey.send.settings</result>
        </action>
```

Action class contains the following 3 instance variables instance with getter and setter

```
    public File upload;
    private String contentType;
    private String filename;
```

However, `upload.getName()` is not getting the actual filename, whereas `contentType` and `filename` properties are `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention for the setters is

```
setX(File file)
setXContentType(String contentType)
setXFileName(String fileName)
```

where X corresponds to the value of the name attribute of the `<s:file />` tag in your jsp page

**Jsp form**

```
<s:form action="doUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <s:file name="upload" label="File"/>
   <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

**Action class**

```
private File upload ;
private String uploadFileName ;
private String uploadContentType ;

// Getters and setters
// ActionSupport methods
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!